# Weird zend fw problem that makes me crazy!

Tags: zend-framework

There is a problem that I can't resolve. I am developing a project and test on my computer which runs as expected. But when I move the project to testing server, which also has Zend Server CE, it gives blank page. Display errors function is ON and I put try catch at the very begining, but it still shows a blank page. When ever I write "exit;" command at the end of related view script, page works normally!

What can couse this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be a problem with your include path.  That's a very common issue when deploying from one server to another.

But clearly it's some kind of fatal error.  I haven't used Zend Server, but in Apache I'd look in the error_log, since any fatal error output ends up there.  Does Zend Server have something similar?

...aha, Zend Server seems to have a log, accessed through **Monitor > Logs** in the admin interface.  Try looking in the **PHP Error Log** for reports of fatal errors.

Comment: The problem is that there are no any fatal errors. when there is any error it just show. I have now updated my framework files with the servers, now it makes the same in my computer too, which make me think of this couse because of version difference.